# Eclipse for c setup, cannot locate stdio.h

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, gcc

I have setup eclipse as per this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KfKvDIrabUw

I have intalled java and GCC on my windows 10 laptop. It cannot build my c project, because I get the error "fatal error: stdio.h -std=gnu99: No such file or directory".

I assume this file exists on my computer *somewhere*, if not by default then with thte GCC that I downloaded and installed. I just need to find, in the hundreds of option menus, the place where I locate the directory. Maybe I'm blind but I can't find it, and if I do, where to I link it to? (Getting a little frustrated if you couldn't tell...)

Many many thanks,
Andy.

Comment: Where did you write `-std=gnu99`?

Comment: I copied that from the error message I received in the console. Apart from that, I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. If anyone else is experiencing this problem, open up the project explorer, right click on your project and open up the properties. Make sure **Text file encoding** and **New text file line delimiter** are both set to **UTF-8**.

It is now working.